# Riverpod removed widget still executes the family provider selector in debug mode

Tags: flutter, riverpod

My state contains a list that the user can modify. Adding new items to the list is fine, however, when you remove items from the list the widget is still executing the `FamilyProvider` selector, which fails since the item it wants to look up was removed.

However this appears to only happen in debug builds on both Windows and Chrome. In Release mode, I cannot reproduce it. On `dartpad.dev` I also cannot reproduce it.

To reproduce click on any of the buttons to remove them and notice the `Error: Bad state: No element`.

Full example:

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final buttons = ref.watch(appStateProvider).buttons;

    print('Rebuild HomePage with $buttons');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Click on any of the buttons to remove the widget'),
            for (final btn in buttons) _ButtonWidget(id: btn.id),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ButtonWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  final int id;

  _ButtonWidget({
    required this.id,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('Rebuild ButtonWidget $id');

    // this one is still being executed, even if the widget is removed.
    final buttonState = ref.watch(buttonStateFamilyProvider(id));

    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final appStateController = ref.read(appStateProvider.notifier);
        final newList = appStateController.state.buttons.toList()
          ..removeWhere((btn) => btn.id == id);

        appStateController.state = AppState(newList);
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      child: Text(buttonState.name),
    );
  }
}

final appStateProvider = StateProvider<AppState>((ref) {
  return const AppState([
    ButtonState(1, 'Button 1'),
    ButtonState(2, 'Button 2'),
  ]);
});

final buttonStateFamilyProvider = Provider.family.autoDispose<ButtonState, int>(
  (ref, id) {
    ref.onCancel(() {
      print('cancelled buttonStateFamilyProvider($id)');
    });

    print('Executing buttonStateFamilyProvider($id)');

    final result = ref.watch(
      appStateProvider.select(
        (state) => state.buttons.firstWhere(
          (btn) => btn.id == id,
        ),
      ),
    );

    print('buttonStateFamilyProvider($id) = $result');

    return result;
  },
);

class AppState with EquatableMixin {
  final List<ButtonState> buttons;

  const AppState(this.buttons);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [buttons];
}

class ButtonState with EquatableMixin {
  final String name;
  final int id;

  const ButtonState(this.id, this.name);

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [name];
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: riverpod_widget_rebuild
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none' 

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.5 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  equatable: ^2.0.5

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [suggested](https://github.com/rrousselGit/riverpod/discussions/2283#discussioncomment-5250075) by Remi: you could cheat with:

```dart
state.buttons.firstWhere(..., orElse: () => ref.state)
```

This will not throw if a provider got rebuilt when an ID got deleted.

Alternative you could make the provider nullable.

```dart
final buttonStateFamilyProvider =
    Provider.family.autoDispose<ButtonState?, int>(
  (ref, id) {
    print('Executing buttonStateFamilyProvider($id)');

    final result = ref.watch(
      appStateProvider.select(
        (state) => state.buttons.firstWhereOrNull(
          (btn) => btn.id == id,
        ),
      ),
    );

    print('buttonStateFamilyProvider($id) = $result');

    return result;
  },
);
```

And in the widget add '!' as it can never be null.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    print('Rebuild ButtonWidget $id');

    // Added '!' since this cannot return null if the widget exists. 
    final buttonState = ref.watch(buttonStateFamilyProvider(id))!;

    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        final appStateController = ref.read(appStateProvider.notifier);
        final newList = appStateController.state.buttons.toList()
          ..removeWhere((btn) => btn.id == id);

        appStateController.state = AppState(newList);
      },
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      child: Text(buttonState.name),
    );
  }
```